# How to sample from a multinomial distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability, distribution, sampling, multinomial

Lets assume that I have a set of probabilities [0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1]. I want to sample the locations from this set of probabilities. e.g. when I sample I should get the location 1 quite often than other locations. I know I can implement this in Matlab (using the command mnrnd) or other languages. However, I would like to know the algorithmic details. I would like to know a very simple algorithm which can be used to sample from a multinomial distribution.

Comment: What value of `n` do you want to use? Not enough information given

Answer (score 4):

### Brute force approach

Create an array containing the cumulative probabilities, in your case `cdf = [0.1, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0]`.  Generate `U`, a uniform(0,1) random value.  Select the first index such that `cdf[i] <= U`. For a small number of outcomes this could be accomplished with a linear search (O(n)), or use binary search (O(log n)) if the number of outcomes is large.

### Alias method

An alias table requires you to use conditional probability to construct a table of primary elements and alias values in such a way that for each primary/alias pair, the total probability is identical.  You then use one random number to choose a column within the table (with equal probability), and a second value to make a binomial choice between the primary and the alias.  Run time is O(1) once the table has been constructed, which takes O(n) effort.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) for details, or [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/aliastable) for a Ruby implementation.  Note that this requires two uniforms per outcome, so it's not an inversion and you can't do fun tricks like generating [antithetic variates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates).

Comment: But OT asked for multinomial, not just some generic discrete finite probability distribution. Not sure if your answer could help...

Comment: shouldn't it be `cdf[i] > U`?